# How to fix RSA Deprecation

Tags: c, openssl, rsa

I have a program to test the throughput of RSA, but the RSA_key is deprecated and I'm not sure how to switch the code over to the new RSA_key.

The program throws the warning:

```
rsa2.c:29:5: warning: ‘RSA_generate_key’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
```

`rsa2.c:29` is:

```
RSA *keypair = RSA_generate_key(KEY_LENGTH, PUB_EXP, NULL, NULL);
```

I know that I need to switch the RSA_generate_key to:

```
int RSA_generate_key_ex(RSA *rsa, int bits, BIGNUM *e, BN_GENCB *cb);
```

but because the new `RSA_key` is an int I'm not sure how to set `RSA *keypair =  int RSA_generate_key_ex(RSA *rsa, int bits, BIGNUM *e, BN_GENCB *cb);`.

My code is:

```
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>  
#define KEY_LENGTH 768 
#define PUB_EXP 65537
#define PRINT_KEYS
#define WRITE_TO_FILE
int main(void) {
    size_t pri_len;            // Length of private key
    size_t pub_len;            // Length of public key
    char   *pri_key;           // Private key
    char   *pub_key;           // Public key
    char   msg[KEY_LENGTH/8] = "hello";  // Message to encrypt
    char   *encrypt = NULL;    // Encrypted message
    char   *decrypt = NULL;    // Decrypted message
    char   *err;               // Buffer for any error messages
    clock_t begin, end; 
    double time_spent; begin = clock();  
    // Generate key pair
    printf("Generating RSA (%d bits) keypair...", KEY_LENGTH);
    fflush(stdout);
    RSA *keypair = RSA_generate_key(KEY_LENGTH, PUB_EXP, NULL, NULL);
    // To get the C-string PEM form:
    BIO *pri = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    BIO *pub = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    PEM_write_bio_RSAPrivateKey(pri, keypair, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    PEM_write_bio_RSAPublicKey(pub, keypair);
    pri_len = BIO_pending(pri);
    pub_len = BIO_pending(pub);
    pri_key = malloc(pri_len + 1);
    pub_key = malloc(pub_len + 1);
    BIO_read(pri, pri_key, pri_len);
    BIO_read(pub, pub_key, pub_len);
    pri_key[pri_len] = '\0';
    pub_key[pub_len] = '\0';
    #ifdef PRINT_KEYS
        printf("\n%s\n%s\n", pri_key, pub_key);
    #endif
    printf("done.\n");

    encrypt = malloc(RSA_size(keypair));
    int encrypt_len;
    err = malloc(130);
    if((encrypt_len = RSA_public_encrypt(strlen(msg)+1, (unsigned char*)msg, (unsigned char*)encrypt,
                                         keypair, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING)) == -1) {
        ERR_load_crypto_strings();
        ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), err);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error encrypting message: %s\n", err);
        goto free_stuff;
    }
    #ifdef WRITE_TO_FILE
    // Write the encrypted message to a file
        FILE *out = fopen("out.bin", "w");
        fwrite(encrypt, sizeof(*encrypt),  RSA_size(keypair), out);
        fclose(out);
        printf("Encrypted message written to file.\n");
        free(encrypt);
        encrypt = NULL;
        // Read it back
        printf("Reading back encrypted message and attempting decryption...\n");
        encrypt = malloc(RSA_size(keypair));
        out = fopen("out.bin", "r");

        fread(encrypt, sizeof(*encrypt), RSA_size(keypair), out);
        fclose(out);
    #endif
    // Decrypt it
    decrypt = malloc(encrypt_len);
    if(RSA_private_decrypt(encrypt_len, (unsigned char*)encrypt, (unsigned char*)decrypt,
                           keypair, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING) == -1) {
        ERR_load_crypto_strings();
        ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), err);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error decrypting message: %s\n", err);
        goto free_stuff;
    }
    printf("Decrypted message: %s\n", decrypt);
    end = clock(); 
    time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC; 
    printf("time spent %f\n", time_spent); 
    free_stuff:
    RSA_free(keypair);
    BIO_free_all(pub);
    BIO_free_all(pri);
    free(pri_key);
    free(pub_key);
    free(encrypt);
    free(decrypt);
    free(err);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The value returned (an int) is not the RSA keypair, it's just a status value indicating success or failure. The RSA keypair is stored in a properly initialized RSA struct pointed by the first argument.

Comment: This question seems distinctly different than the one it is linked to as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this could work for you (adapted using [this link](https://www.codepool.biz/how-to-use-openssl-generate-rsa-keys-cc.html)):

```c
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>  
#define KEY_LENGTH 768 
#define PUB_EXP 65537
#define PRINT_KEYS
#define WRITE_TO_FILE
int main(void) {
    size_t pri_len;            // Length of private key
    size_t pub_len;            // Length of public key
    char   *pri_key;           // Private key
    char   *pub_key;           // Public key
    char   msg[KEY_LENGTH/8] = "hello";  // Message to encrypt
    char   *encrypt = NULL;    // Encrypted message
    char   *decrypt = NULL;    // Decrypted message
    char   *err;               // Buffer for any error messages
    clock_t begin, end; 
    RSA    *r = NULL;
    BIGNUM *bne = NULL;
    int ret;
    double time_spent; begin = clock();  
    // Generate key pair
    printf("Generating RSA (%d bits) keypair...", KEY_LENGTH);
    fflush(stdout);

    // RSA *keypair = RSA_generate_key(KEY_LENGTH, PUB_EXP, NULL, NULL);
    // 1. generate rsa key
    bne = BN_new();
    ret = BN_set_word(bne, PUB_EXP);
    if(ret != 1){
        goto free_stuff;
    }
    r = RSA_new();
    ret = RSA_generate_key_ex(r, KEY_LENGTH, bne, NULL);
    if(ret != 1){
        goto free_stuff;
    }

    // To get the C-string PEM form:
    BIO *pri = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    BIO *pub = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    PEM_write_bio_RSAPrivateKey(pri, keypair, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    PEM_write_bio_RSAPublicKey(pub, keypair);
    pri_len = BIO_pending(pri);
    pub_len = BIO_pending(pub);
    pri_key = malloc(pri_len + 1);
    pub_key = malloc(pub_len + 1);
    BIO_read(pri, pri_key, pri_len);
    BIO_read(pub, pub_key, pub_len);
    pri_key[pri_len] = '\0';
    pub_key[pub_len] = '\0';
    #ifdef PRINT_KEYS
        printf("\n%s\n%s\n", pri_key, pub_key);
    #endif
    printf("done.\n");
    // Get the message to encrypt
   // printf("Message to encrypt: ");
   // fgets(msg, KEY_LENGTH-1, stdin);
   // msg[strlen(msg)-1] = '\0';
    // Encrypt the message
    encrypt = malloc(RSA_size(keypair));
    int encrypt_len;
    err = malloc(130);
    if((encrypt_len = RSA_public_encrypt(strlen(msg)+1, (unsigned char*)msg, (unsigned char*)encrypt,
                                         keypair, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING)) == -1) {
        ERR_load_crypto_strings();
        ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), err);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error encrypting message: %s\n", err);
        goto free_stuff;
    }
    #ifdef WRITE_TO_FILE
    // Write the encrypted message to a file
        FILE *out = fopen("out.bin", "w");
        fwrite(encrypt, sizeof(*encrypt),  RSA_size(keypair), out);
        fclose(out);
        printf("Encrypted message written to file.\n");
        free(encrypt);
        encrypt = NULL;
        // Read it back
        printf("Reading back encrypted message and attempting decryption...\n");
        encrypt = malloc(RSA_size(keypair));
        out = fopen("out.bin", "r");

        fread(encrypt, sizeof(*encrypt), RSA_size(keypair), out);
        fclose(out);
    #endif
    // Decrypt it
    decrypt = malloc(encrypt_len);
    if(RSA_private_decrypt(encrypt_len, (unsigned char*)encrypt, (unsigned char*)decrypt,
                           keypair, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING) == -1) {
        ERR_load_crypto_strings();
        ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), err);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error decrypting message: %s\n", err);
        goto free_stuff;
    }
    printf("Decrypted message: %s\n", decrypt);
    end = clock(); 
    time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC; 
    printf("time spent %f\n", time_spent); 

free_stuff:
    RSA_free(keypair);
    BIO_free_all(pub);
    BIO_free_all(pri);
    free(pri_key);
    free(pub_key);
    free(encrypt);
    free(decrypt);
    free(err);
    RSA_free(r);
    BN_free(bne);
    return 0;
}
```